# Django, Ajax url not found in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm making the website using django, python and javascript.
I get an error
**'Not found: /schedule/{% url 'schedule_delete' %}'** when I use the ajax in js file

fullcalendar.js

```
function eventElementHandlers(event, eventElement) {
    eventElement
        .click(function(ev) {
            var start = event.start; 
            var id = event.id;
            var title = event.title;

            var allData = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}', "id":id, "start":start, "title":title};
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'schedule_delete' %}", 
                type: "POST",
                data: allData, 
                dataType: "json", 

                success: function(response){
                    alert("success!");
                    $('#used_session'+id).html(response.used_session);

                },
                error:function(error){
                    alert("fail!");
                }
            });
  }
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns= [
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^schedule_delete/$', views.schedule_delete, name='schedule_delete'),

]
```

I also made schedule_delete in views.py.

Why url is wrong?? The same url format was okay in the other template. Is url foramt different depending on the django template or js file??

Any help will be very helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: keep the url in the js like this url: "/schedule_delete",

Comment: 1. it will add /schedule_delete/ to your current url
2. If you want to use it: use : url: "{% url 'app_name:schedule_delete' %}",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your javascript files have no access to a django context, since you are only rendering html files through django. What you need to do is put your javascript inline in your templates to be able to access the {% url %} template tag.

An alternative way is to create for example a data-url html attribute which you set to your url, and access that attribute in your javascript file.

Edit:

I am not sure what your html looks like but I assume your eventElement is a button.

```
<button data-url="{% url 'schedule-delete' %}"></button>
```

When you click the button your event handler is called in your js file:

```
function eventElementHandlers(event, eventElement) {
    eventElement
        .click(function(ev) {

            ...

            $.ajax({
                url: $(eventElement).data('url'),
                ...
```

Comment: I understand, and that is exactly what I am trying to explain. You add a custom html attribute to your eventElement, set it to your django url, and than you can query this attribute through jQuery for its value in your javascript file

Answer (score 2):

you can not use `"{% url 'schedule_delete' %}"` in your js file. You first need to take this url in an input in your html form and then read it using javascript or jquery.

In html write.

```
<button ... id="ajax-button" data-ajax-target="{% url 'named-url' %}">
```

and in javascript simply do

```
$.post($("#ajax-button").attr("data-ajax-target"), ... );
```

this is just an example you can do similar in other ways also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm using fullcalendar template. So, clicking the eventelement event happens only in the fullcalendar.js. I tried to do same thing(clicking the event) in the html, but I failed. Is there any way handling ajax in js file?

Comment: You can add an data-url attribute to the button (_data-url="{% url 'named-url' %}"_) you are clicking, and than you have access to your url in your javascript.

Comment: How I go to the function eventElementHandlers(event, eventElement) {} in the html? I will put the href in my div. What href format do I need to access that js?

Comment: Becuase I have to transmit the data to the url, I don't want to just go to the url. I wanna go to the url with data.

Comment: how I use the named-url in my javascript??

Comment: Ah, I gave up the ajax, instaed I use the url tag. Thanks for yours all comments and answers!

Answer (score 0):

You are making a request to the url `/schedule/schedule_delete/` but it looks like your urls.py is setup only to handle the url `/schedule_delete/`. Are you including the schedule urls.py from a main urls.py?

Also as the other answerer noted, you can't use django template variables in a javascript file.